# Sublime Text 3 の右クリック -> Open in Browser で日本語名のフォルダに内包されているファイルを開きたい

Tags: sublimetext

Sublime Text 3 の右クリック -> Open in Browser で日本語名のフォルダに内包されているファイルを開きたいです。
現状、日本語名を含んでいるフォルダに内包されているファイルを開こうとすると、

```
File "open_in_browser in /Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/Packages/Default.sublime-package", line 7, in run
  File "./webbrowser.py", line 70, in open_new_tab
  File "./webbrowser.py", line 62, in open
  File "./webbrowser.py", line 635, in open
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 45-46: ordinal not in range(128)
```

とコンソールに出力されブラウザで表示はされません。
が、ファイルパスが全て半角英数字で構成されている場合、Open in Browserで問題なくデフォルトブラウザーで開けます。

どうすれば日本語名を含んでいるフォルダに内包されているファイルをOpen in Browserで開けるようになるでしょうか。
解決策がお分かりになる方がいましたらご教授願いたいです。

Answer (score 1):

あてずっぽうですので、間違ってたらすみません。
Sublime Text が入っているフォルダから webbrowser.py を探し、635行目を探します。
そこの上に `def open(self, url, 何か...)` という関数が宣言されているのでそのすぐ下で

```
url = url.encode("utf-8")
```

を入れると直ると思います。
※バックアップを取ってから弄って下さい。